# delete_post hook - deleting multiple items

Tags: posts

I am using `delete_post` hook.

```
add_action('delete_post', array($this, 'remove_audio_file')); // delete post event
```

(Using it inside the class).

When I delete a single post I have no problem retrieving its ID.

```
global $post;
```

However, when I delete multiple posts (2 or more) `$post` becomes `NULL`.
Can you advise why is that / what I am doing wrong ?

EDIT:

```
function remove_audio_file() {
        global $post;
        if ($post != NULL) {
           $unique_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_unique_id', true);
            $username = get_userdata($post->post_author)->user_login;
            $uploadrr = new bt_uploader();
            $dirPath = $uploadrr->audio_folder() . $username . '/' . $unique_id;
            if (is_dir($dirPath)) {
                foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirPath, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $path) {
                    $path->isFile() ? unlink($path->getPathname()) : rmdir($path->getPathname());
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for messed up styling / indenting. Not sure how I can edit post.

Comment: You need to show more code - such as `remove_audio_file`.

Comment: Added remove_audio_file function.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how that hook is meant to be used:

```php
do_action( 'delete_post', int $postid, WP_Post $post )
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_post/

The action gives you the post ID and a post object.

So don't access `$_GET` or the global `$post` object, instead use the what the action gives you.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting multiple items, $_GET['post'] becomes an array with numeric keys starting from 0. To access current item that is being deleted, use global $post_del. This is identical to global $post so all methods and procedures would work the same way. This is *not* documented on WP Codex. I have found it out myself via debugging.